# Why does the set $\{ x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x^2 \le 5\}$ not have a greatest element?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-set-theory, maxima-minima, supremum-and-infimum

I have just learned what the definition is of a supremum, and I am confused to something my textbooks says:

*Subsets with a supremum don't have to have a greatest element, for example:*$$(0,3):  = \{x \in \mathbb{R} \mid 0 < x < 3\}$$and$$\{ x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x^2 \le 5\}$$

I understand the first example since we know that the supremum is $3$ but the subset doesn't have a greatest element since it must be less than $3$. I however do not understand the second one. If we solve  $x^2 \le 5$ I believe we get $-\sqrt{5} \le x \le \sqrt{5}$. Wouldn't this mean that $\sqrt{5}$ is the greatest element in this subset?

Comment: Note that $\sqrt{5}$ is not a rational number, though, so it doesn't lie in your set.

Comment: notice that the set consist only of rational numbers, but the square root of 5 is not rational.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

But in your second example, $x \in \mathbb{Q}$, BUT $\sqrt{5} \notin \mathbb{Q}$, so the greatest (maximal) element *in* the second set **cannot be** $\sqrt{5}$.

$\sqrt{5}$ ***is*** the supremum of the set, but it is not the greatest element (i.e., *maximal element*) in the set (as a maximal element of a set must be *IN the set*).  The supremum of a set need *not be in the set*, and a set may have a supremum, without a greatest element, as you note in the first set.) In this case, like the first example you provide, there is no maximal element in the set.

$$(2)\quad\{x \in \mathbb{Q} \mid x^2 \le 5\} \iff \{x \in \mathbb{Q}: -\sqrt{5} \le x \le \sqrt{5}\} \iff \{x \in \mathbb{Q}\;\; \land \;\;x \in [-\sqrt{5}, \sqrt{5}]\}.$$
So $(2)$ ***excludes irrationals*** like $-\sqrt{5}$ and $\sqrt{5}$.  
Note that $(2)$ is precisely the same set as $\{x \in \mathbb{Q}: \sqrt{5} < x < \sqrt{5}\}$ (using the "strict" inequality, "$<$" to replace "$\le$")

Comment: Yes it is, thank you.

Answer (score 6):

It would, if $\sqrt{5}$ were in the subset. But it isn't, since $\sqrt{5}\notin \mathbb Q$.

Comment: Oh, I see. careless mistake, sorry.